# PDF editor and viewer for Ubuntu

Tags: pdf, editor

I am starting to use Ubuntu as my main system for academic activities due to its security and performance. Well, in WINDOWS I use Adobe Acrobat PRO DC, especially for the following functions:

- Delete pages;
- Organize pages;
- Edit metadata;

In that sense, I would like to ask your help on any program that performs, IN SPECIAL, these three functions.

Answer (score 0):

So I am a security and systems/network engineer running Ubuntu as my daily driver.
Not sure what advantages the OS on itself really gives you when it comes to security. I just like the fact that a lot of people use it, so the troubleshooting is relatively available and the GNOME desktop isn't bad. I tried Arch but having rolling release is a PITA. People would recommend Kali but it has too much stuff I don't really use too much day to day and I like to choose it all myself. My point is Ubuntu isn't the epitome of security in any way.

My suggestions for a PDF reader: PDFsam Basic en PDFsam Enhanced (paid)
AFAIK this allows you to split pages of PDF's and also merge them together in 1 doc. Enhanced has many many features.

Linux also has commandline tools to inspect metadata such as exif or file.